# Filtering the records with a left-join in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join

I have two tables in Bigquery - raw1_data and mapping_data. The intention is to use the mapping_data table to map the products from the raw1_data table to produce the final_data table.

**mapping_data**

| dataset | country | category | brand | new_category | new_brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| raw1 | A | abc | pqr | bsq | pqr |
| raw1 | B | xyz | efg |  |  |
| raw1 | X | abc | lmn | bsq | lmn |
| raw1 | Y | xyz | hij | xyz | hij |
| raw2 | X | abc | lmn | abc | lmn |
| raw3 | B | xyz | efg | xyz | efg |

**raw_data**

| country | category | brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | abc | efg |
| B | xyz | efg |
| X | abc | hij |
| X | abc | lmn |
| Y | xyz | hij |

**final_data**

| country | category | brand | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | abc | efg | Unmapped |
| X | abc | hij | Unmapped |
| X | bsq | lmn | Mapped |
| Y | xyz | hij | Mapped |

The rules of mapping are -

1. Match the country, category, brand columns from raw1_data to
   country,category,brand columns in mapping_data. Also, we need to
   match only to the rows where dataset column is "raw1" because
   mapping_data table is used by different datasets and has mapping
   criteria for different datasets.
2. If the same country,category,brand is found in mapping_data table,
   then category and brand for the final_data table would be
   new_category and new_brand from the mapping_data table. The Status
   would be marked as 'Mapped'.
3. If there is no match found in mapping_data table, the category and
   brand of the final_data table would remian the same as in raw1_data
   table. But Status would be 'Unmapped'.
4. In case after matching the new_category and new_brand is NULL as
   seen for B,xyz,efg combination, then remove such rows from the
   final_data table.

I have thought of several approaches and finally arrived at the code below. Is this the best possible solution or is there any other way I can achieve this without having to use a subquery and case statements? The number of records in the raw1_data table is in millions while the number of records in the mapping_data table is a few hundred or thousands.

**Code**

```
with mapping_cte as (
    SELECT
        rd.country,
        rd.category,
        rd.brand,
        md.dataset,
        md.country as country1,
        md.category as category1,
        md.brand as brand1,
        md.new_category,
        md.new_brand,
        CASE
            WHEN md.country IS NULL THEN STRUCT(
                rd.category AS mapped_category,
                rd.brand AS mapped_brand,
                'Unmapped' AS status
            )
            WHEN md.country IS NOT NULL
            AND (
                new_category IS NULL
                OR new_brand IS NULL
            ) THEN STRUCT(
                NULL AS mapped_category,
                NULL AS mapped_brand,
                'remove' as status
            )
            ELSE STRUCT(
                new_category AS mapped_category,
                new_brand AS mapped_brand,
                'Mapped' AS status
            )
        END as fields
    FROM
        raw1_data rd
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mapping_data md ON rd.country = md.country
        AND rd.category = md.category
        AND rd.brand = md.brand
        AND md.dataset = 'raw1'
)
select
    mapping_cte.country,
    mapping_cte.fields.mapped_category,
    mapping_cte.fields.mapped_brand,
    mapping_cte.fields.status
from
    mapping_cte
where
    mapping_cte.fields.status != 'remove'
order by
    1,
    2,
    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select country, 
  (case status_flag
    when true then struct(new_category as category, new_brand as brand, 'Mapped' as status)
    else struct(category, brand, 'Unmapped' as status)
  end).*
from (
  select country, category, brand, new_category, new_brand, 
    not m.country is null as status_flag
  from raw_data r
  left join (select * from mapping_data where dataset = 'raw1') m
  using(country, category, brand) 
)
where not (status_flag and new_category is null and new_brand is null)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was comparing my solution with the one you have provided. The main difference as I understand is that I am using a derived struct element to filter out the unnecessary rows while yours is a much simpler approach. I tried both the queries and I am getting the same result and performance is also pretty even. Am I missing something out here, I think the left join conditions are also the same even though it is written in a different way in both the queries. The solution you've provided is also more readable. Can you let me know if there is a significant difference?